# Cannot load PHPMailer 5.5 on CakePHP 2

Tags: cakephp-2.0, phpmailer

In an unrelated, vanilla PHP project, I simply have this:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

It pulls in just fine. Following CakePHP 2.10's standards, I put all associated (composer'd) files in the app/Vendor folder and try this in my controller:

```
public function index($load = null) {
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    include(APP . 'Vendor' . DS.'autoload.php');
```

I get:
**syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)**

Any attempts to move the *use* around end up not working, so I ignore them and try to get it to work without namespaces.

```
require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS.'autoload.php');
require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS.'phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php');
```

I know it's loading the PHP file via require_once, and that file includes the PHPMailer class. I get this error:

```
Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found
```

But I know that class has to be present somewhere, because I loaded it. Code looks like this, to call it:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
            try {
                //Server settings
                $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
                $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
                $mail->Host = 'smtp.zoho.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
```

etc. So I'm not sure if this version of PHPMailer refuses to work without namespaces, which CakePHP 2 doesn't support? All other questions on Google do not seem to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting the `use` statements in the wrong place; they need to go at the top of your file (after any `namespace` declaration) as they are not block-scoped. [Read the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).

You can mix namespaced and non-namespaced code, you just need to be aware that it's going on.

Comment: Well. I am ashamed.